# Are Wonder woman and Superwoman the same character?

Tags: dc, wonder-woman, superwoman

Are Wonder woman and Superwoman the same character? I have tried looking it up but I can not find anything.

Comment: The question is a real question (as such that it has an actual canon answer AND I know the answer) and is a question that could possibly be confusing given the DC Universe's chaotic and long history. I will only reopen if if the community is okay with it.

Comment: I assume he's asking about the Crime Syndicate's Superwoman, but the Batgirl tag  throws me off a bit. Did Superwoman have an appearance in Batgirl during Forever Evil?

Comment: @Thaddeus - VTRO. The fact that you take the question seriously is more weighty for me than 5 random people with less demonstrated knowledge of canon (with all due respect to those who cast close votes). "chaotic and long history" just about sums up how I feel about DC (and marvel) anytime I try to dig into details.

Comment: @Boelabaal - low-rep users can't create their own tags, and we probably have batgirl tag but not superwoman or wonder woman ones. I retagged

Comment: The real problem here is while this is a weak question, a modest bit of effort could resolve this reasonably well. I just happen to know the answer off the top of my head, but when I went to see if you could find answers online, they were there and not terribly difficult to figure out. So that's why I didn't reopen it immediately.

Comment: @Thaddeus - Reopened. I eagerly await your answer :-)

Comment: to be honest, my close vote was because he asked about wonder woman and superwoman and tagged it 'batgirl', which made me assume he was just throwing out random female characters and had no interest in a real answer. the fact that Thaddeus gave one anyway is, as usual, amazing :)

Answer (score 20):

#### DC Comics' Wonder Woman has, like so many DC characters existed on multiple parallel Earths in the Pre-Crisis multiverse. Her Earth-1 and Earth-2 counterparts resemble the character we recognize today. But on Earth-3, Wonder Woman, like all of the other major heroes of the Justice League, were inverted in their temperament and behavior. They were evil. On this world, Wonder Woman was called Superwoman.

[image]

- Superwoman is the name of several fictional characters, who are supervillains appearing in stories published by DC Comics. All are evil or corrupted alternate-universe counterparts of Wonder Woman. Superwoman first appeared in Justice League of America #29 (August 1964) alongside the rest of the Crime Syndicate of America.
- Superwoman has all of the abilities we have come to associate with Wonder Woman including: Super strength, speed, agility, reflexes, stamina, endurance, and the power of flight. Superwoman was a superior hand-to-hand combatant, possessed a healing factor and used magical weapons including her Lasso of Submission (Earth-3 Version of the Lasso of Truth), a weaponized tiara, and a magical sword. And where Wonder Woman has in recent decades become more aggressive and willing to kill if necessary, Superwoman has always been capable of homicide without much urging.

#### What confuses most fans:

- DC Comics has also, over the decades, played with the idea of a Superwoman (a character who is a female equivalent of Superman) in many ways. In some forms she has been a Kryptonian who manages to somehow survive the destruction of Krypton, in others, she is Kara, Superman's cousin, all grown up. In a few she is a human using technology to replicate superhuman abilities.

[image]

*These are just four of the better known versions of Superwoman to have existed in the DC Universe.*

- This mixup and lack of thought given to the names of these characters can only be blamed on editoral oversight and no consideration to the potential confusion this might have created in the future. It is likely one of the major reasons we have never seen a Superwoman (heroic identity) ever seem to take off, though DC has tried numerous times.

Answer (score 0):

Super Woman is an evil Amazon. She isn't Lois, that was just DC sloppy writing. In her pre crisis appearances, Lois appeared too.
Super Woman was an evil Amazon, vain and aggressive.
She should be renamed Suprema to separate her away from Superwoman and the Superman family. Suprema was the original name coined for Wonder Woman... so it fits and has a haughty vanity to it.
Ive always liked Super Woman and hope she continues to appear.